# How to generate pdf thumbnail in azure node function

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, azure-functions

I am building a microservice which involves generating a thumbnail from pdf using azure node function. 
I could find some libraries like pdf-thumbnail to convert pdf to thumbnail, but since they have binary dependencies (requires imagemagick and ghostscript installed), it doesn't work on azure function app.
How can I install the native executables on azure node function app?
Or is there any javascript-only node libraries to generate thumbnail from pdf?

Comment: Not a Ghostscript question.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install these two packages before use them. Please go to your function on Azure portal and click "Platform features" --> "Advanced tools (Kudu)".
[image]

Then it will open a kudu window, please click "Debug console" --> "CMD" --> "site" --> "wwwroot". And input the command below to init a package.json.

```
npm init
```

[image]

After run the "npm init" command, it will remind you to provide the package name, version, description..... You just need to press enter key and it will generate the package.json with default value.
[image]

Next step, please input "npm install" command to install "imagemagick" package and "ghostscript" package.

```
npm install imagemagick
```

```
npm install ghostscript
```

[image]

After that, we can use these two packages in our nodejs code in azure function by

```
const im = require('imagemagick');
const gs = require('ghostscript-js');
```

For more information about these two packages, please refer to :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghostscript-js

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I like the details, but as I mentioned, the two libraries require on native executables to be installed previously. Could you please tell me more about how to do this?

Comment: Hi @think-serious, I'm so sorry but I'm still not so clear about "require on native executables to be installed". Could you please describe your problem in more detail ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I need the same thing.  At one time v2 supported ghostscript but now my function is broken.  I'm using pdf2png which requires ghostscript.